# Partial target and partial trigger is taking so long

Tags: oracle-adf

This is my situation: 
I am making a jsff for sell of products.
I designed it with several images that represent products. Every image is surrounded by a command link.
Every time I click into the image I need to accumulate the value and show the output in an input text.

My problem is that the action is taking so long. So, if as a customer I need to buy 3 x product, I need to clock the image (command link) three times.
I add a partial trigger to the component, alternative, I added a partial target for add the partial trigger programmatically, but in the two options is taking a while.

Do I am doing something wrong?
Is there other option for do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript is the solution.